# Plot Button to Add Latitude and Longitude to input fields? Geocode

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I have a form and one of my inputs lets my user input their office location (address)

From this address I want to plot a google map on their profile. I would like them to supply the long's and lat's but they will have no idea how. Is there a way the user can populate the long and lat fields by entering an address into the address field and then pressing a plot button which will return the long and lats and input them into the appropriate fields.

My code so far is as follows (I made a JSFiddle to avoid putting a lot of code within this message)

http://jsfiddle.net/F2snX/

A snippet of 1 location is as follows (But better to see full jsfiddle example)

```
<li id="field_15_92" class="gfield">
<label class="gfield_label" for="input_15_92">Solicitor Practice Address</label>
    <div class="ginput_container">
        <input id="input_15_92" class="medium" type="text" tabindex="3" value="" name="input_92">
        <input type="button" id="plot1" value="Plot" /><br />
    </div>
<div class="gfield_description">Enter Address Location and Press Plot Button </div>
</li>
<li id="field_15_166" class="gfield">
<label class="gfield_label" for="input_15_166">Main Practice Opening Hours</label>
    <div class="ginput_container">
        <input id="input_15_166" class="medium" type="text" tabindex="4" value="" name="input_166">
    </div>
<div class="gfield_description">Enter Office Opening Hours</div>
</li>
<li id="field_15_167" class="gfield">
<label class="gfield_label" for="input_15_167">Main Practice Map Longitude </label>
    <div class="ginput_container">
        <input id="input_15_167" class="medium" type="text" tabindex="5" value="" name="input_167">
    </div>
<div class="gfield_description">Enter Longitude Coordinates</div>
</li>
<li id="field_15_169" class="gfield">
<label class="gfield_label" for="input_15_169">Main Practice Map Latitude</label>
    <div class="ginput_container">
        <input id="input_15_169" class="medium" type="text" tabindex="6" value="" name="input_169">
    </div>
<div class="gfield_description">Enter Latitude Coordinates</div>
</li>
```

Thanks

Note: My Wordpress theme is using Google Maps API v3 if that helps with anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are basically two ways how you can approach this problem:

1. Let the user enter an address and find out the geocoordinates yourself. See the description of the [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) for a full feature set.
2. Or you draw a draggable marker on the map and let the user drag the marker to their location. You can find a good explanation in [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968559/retrieve-latitude-and-longitude-of-a-draggable-pin-via-google-maps-api-v3).
3. Or you combine the two apporaches. Let the user enter their address, and if the geocoding result is somehow not sufficient, they may drag the marker to the correct location. [Here is an example by Google](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/singlegeocode.html) that exactly does this.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Although I was hoping I could just have them enter the address to the first field and pressing plot would plot the long's and lat's. I use woo theme Listings and when adding a location on the backend it does exactly this. Enter an address, press plot and all the fields are filled in for you. So I know it can be done just not sure how exactly..thanks again and I will see if I can do the point 2

Comment: See the added example above - but instead of opening the `infoWindow` in the `dragend` handler you would update your form fields.

Comment: awesome, that looks like what I am after and what you suggest about the info window makes a lot of sense. However I am still not sure (/technical enough) to know how to populate the input fields based on this. Do u think you could suggest some code?