# Hot to get Google map marker position in fields

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have this code

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Define the latitude and longitude positions
            var latitude = parseFloat("00.000000");
            var longitude = parseFloat("00.000000");
            var latlngPos = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            // Set up options for the Google map
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 10,
                center: latlngPos,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            // Define the map
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
            // Add the marker
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlngPos,
                draggable: true,
                map: map,
                title: "PC Pro Offices"
            });
        });
    </script>
```

How can I get the marker latitude and longitude after it has been dragged and put it in one or two fields.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieve latitude and longitude of a draggable pin via Google Maps API V3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968559/retrieve-latitude-and-longitude-of-a-draggable-pin-via-google-maps-api-v3)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found [this](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-samples-v3/source/browse/trunk/draggable-markers/draggable-markers.html?spec=svn49&r=49)... for the others with the same problem.