# How to get latitude and longitude after drag marker?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to get location after I dragged the marker on google map and pop up in toast.Anyone has solution for this?

Comment: Have a look at this, the code is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968559/retrieve-latitude-and-longitude-of-a-draggable-pin-via-google-maps-api-v3

Comment: thank you @FranciscoMelicias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener`. From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener):

> **public abstract void onMarkerDragEnd (Marker marker)**
>
> Called when a marker has finished being dragged. The marker's location can be accessed via getPosition().