# How to make place picker like Uber in android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an taxi app and I want to add pick place Like Uber.
Any help please.

[**video of desired feature**](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vyUyx1l9tjG7B5DWyEgc1GNpkC_DOeJy)

Comment: Whats a very broad question, share some code the specific problem

Comment: @TamirAbutbul "Whats a very broad question, share some code " how can i send code for thing i can not do it (watch the video )... i need code for that or method to make it  .. please before add comment think !!!

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the Place Picker is already deprecated as of January 29,2019 and will be turned off on July 29,2019, you may see the documentation for [Place Picker](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/placepicker) to learn more.

As a workaround, you may use a draggable marker instead of Place Picker, you may see this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38070752/how-to-get-latitude-and-longitude-after-drag-marker) as an example.

Answer (score -1):

why not of how to picking the location, references: https://github.com/sonbuiGFD/grab-uber-map-location-picker